# deepstream.io docker run error on OSX

Tags: docker, deepstream.io

I've tried running the official docker container on OSX10.11.

When I download and run on Kitematic, it gives me an error: `Error: No config file found`.

I've run the standard ubuntu container and it has worked correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid so, we're currently looking into it as part of https://github.com/deepstreamIO/docker/issues/2